# Programming C++ on Linux vs Programming C++ on Linux VM in Windows

Tags: c++, linux, windows, unix

Is there any difference between learning to program C++ on Linux as opposed to learning via using a Linux VM, on Windows?

My initial guess is that there is no difference - the VM simply acts as if it were a normal Linux OS?

I am doing this to become particular with C++ programming on Linux, including the Linux kernel, how Linux works, IPC, sockets, shared memory, pipes etc.

Comment: The significant difference is that you're not enveloping yourself in Linux and probably won't get very far with your endeavour. Other than that, the environment is the same.

Comment: @sftrabbit If i'm in Linux on a VM, surely the only difference is what happens before I "open" the OS? Once I am in Linux- its normal Linux?

Comment: Yes, it is. My point was that you'd be better off fully immersing yourself in it.

Comment: One might differ regarding that opinion. There's nothing fundamentally wrong with programming in a VM, and you will not see any practical difference. There is no real advantage of being "fully immersed". There may however be very notable disadvantages with being "fully immersed". Inferior workflow or the excess amount of work when you "break" your computer (which is 2 clicks to repair in a VM) are two examples.

Comment: OP, for what you want to do you won't notice a difference with a vm or standalone machine.  I'll be contrary to Damon though and vote for the latter as an overall learning experience.  There is something to be said for the psychological pressure of having a useless piece of metal on your desk until you are really forced to learn to appreciate it and make it sing.  So I vote would be to throw away the crutch.

Comment: @sftrabbit: If by "better" you mean "much worse", then you're right, otherwise, no.

Comment: I suggest to use a real Linux and to take time to learn using it well. Having Linux on your real screen will help you a big lot. Don't forget that you can dual boot your laptop: use Windows to play, and Linux for work & learning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably the biggest issue you will run into with a VM will come when you are writing multi-threaded programs, or doing IPC on shared data.  Unfortunately because of the way most VM's work, you can end up masking timing issues that would cause crashes on a "real" machine natively running the Linux kernel, or at least un-desirable behavior.  For instance, a data-race that may appear benign on a VM because it doesn't crash during run-time could cause, because of the inherently faster timing on a physical machine, a true data-race that may be very hard to debug.  Another example of timing-related issues that could occur might be where you have multiple processes writing to a pipe with a single reader.  Because of the speed of a VM, you might observe behavior where every writing process is able to  atomically write their entire payload into a pipe, even if that payload is larger than the guaranteed atomicity of `PIPE_MAX` ... if you programmed for that type of behavior, on a real-machine you could end up with a big surprise as anything over `PIPE_MAX` gets interleaved with other processes writing to the pipe.

So in the end, the fact that you are able to observe a lack of process data corruption or crashes from potential data-races while doing multi-threaded programming or shared data IPC on a VM does not assure that your program is actually data-race free, or that it will not crash on a physical machine where the timing of interleaved operations will be much faster.  The speed of the VM could simply be masking those issue for you.

Comment: As the overheads of modern VM like VMWare is very low this surprises me. If you only assign a single CPU to the VM this is of course logical (I remember loads of programs having troubles on the first hyper threading CPU's because of the more critical timings). But is this also true if you assign multiple CPU's to the virtual machine with the better VM's out there? Could you provide some links to papers on the subject? I would be very interested in reading more about this.

Comment: The overhead of VMware is low, but there is overhead, also known as the "probe effect" ... I've seen personally where a VM can mask hidden data-race issues due to pathological timing, that because of the lack of overhead in a physical machine, become problems when tested in a native environment. If your program is data-race free, then the correctness of your program is assured in both a VM and native environment. But the VM can mask data-races that accidentally do exist ... in theory any slower machine can mask interleaved memory access issues.